# SVN 1.8 Compatible Client with GUI for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gratis, linux, ubuntu, version-control

I'm looking for an SVN GUI for Ubuntu, It needs to be compatible with SVN 1.8 as some of the office run Windows with the latest Tortoise SVN.

I've tried RabbitVCS, RapidSVN and even TortoiseSVN under Wine with no luck.  Ideally, it should be free (as in beer).

Currently I'm using the SVN plugin for sublime, which works well, but I would love a way to inspect remote repos (mounted over a sshfs folder) and view their history.

Comment: Could you be more precise what you are looking for in that Program? Why a GUI and not the command line tools? Whats missing in the ones you state? RabbitVCS has SVN 1.8 support http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/support/matrix

Comment: I was looking for all the functionality and ease of use that TortoiseSVN has on Windows, for linux.  Since then I've just used a mixture of the Sublime SVN plugin and the SVN command line client, which I've been very happy with.  This question was asked a while ago now and I'm sure rabbitVCS works well, but at the time it didn't work for me.